# What data should be provided to InsertAfter() and InsertBefore() in a Linked List

Tags: c#, data-structures

I'm building my own linked list in C#. I'm not asking for you to do my homework. Hopefully something can be cleared up for me though.

**The simple answer may be to this sub-question:**
Should a linked list contain only unique values? It's not explained anywhere, so it's odd to me that methods like Remove() and Find() exist since they search by the Node's key/value. It will always only find/remove the first instance.

e.g.,

```
// linkedList = {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
linkedList.Remove(1);
// linkedList = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

**The Meat:**
So far, all of my methods that create nodes don't return anything (per the homework). So whenever I create a node, I can't access it directly except for by value. Yet, the homework says that the InsertAfter() and InsertBefore() methods should accept a node and a key(value).

`InsertAfter(node, key)`;

The only workaround I can think of is to use the Find() method to find a node and pass that in as the first param. It seems hacky though, and it would have to return type Node.

Should I be returning values to store nodes? Should I actually be passing in two `Node.Value`s to the methods and not actually a whole node and a key for another one?

Here's some of my code:

**Node Class**
public class Node

```
{
   public Node Next;
   public object Value;
}
```

**AddToEnd**

```
public void AddToEnd(object value)
{
    Node temp = new Node();
    temp.Value = value;
    if (Head.Value == null)
    {
        Head.Value = value;
    }
    else
    {
        Node currentNode = Head;
        while (currentNode.Next != null)
        {
            currentNode = currentNode.Next;
        }
        currentNode.Next = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should a linked list contain only unique values?

No. To make it more clear you can rename `Find` to `FindFirst` or `FindLast` or `FindAfterIndex`, etc.

> The only workaround I can think of is to use the Find() method to find a node and pass that in as the first param.

I would do exactly the same. However the users of the linked-list don't have to be aware of implementation details, such as there's a class called `Node` that carries data, and so on. Therefore, I would make a method called `FindNode` and make it `private`. Therefore the publicly accessible `Find` method only returns the index of (first) value found, and internally I will use the other `FindNode` private method to deal with insertion, and other optimised operations.

Also to avoid repeated code, I'd rewrite the `Find` method to call `FindNode` internally as well.

Comment: Thanks for the additional note about the private variables!